# Why doesn't symlinked configuration files work when httpd starts?

Tags: apache-http-server

I'm working to setup an new reverse proxy to replace an old one. While I'm testing, I have the vhosts pointing to the test servers, but to make the switch-over easy I planned on having 2 versions of each vhost config, one for the production version of the proxied server, and one for the test version, a la:

```bsh
[root@rp01 /]# ls -l /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts/data.conf*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   14 Aug  2 15:12 /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts/data.conf -> data.conf.test
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1029 Aug  2 13:24 /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts/data.conf.prod
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1029 Aug  2 13:24 /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts/data.conf.test
```

but if I do it like this, httpd won't start, throws a *Permission denied* on the symlink:

```bsh
[root@rp01 /]# systemctl start httpd
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
[root@rp01 /]# journalctl -xe
Server...
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
-- 
-- Unit httpd.service has begun starting up.
Aug 02 15:20:13 rp01.******** httpd[1265]: httpd: Syntax error on line 356 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 24 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts/data.conf: Permission denied
Aug 02 15:20:13 rp01.******** systemd[1]: httpd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 02 15:20:13 rp01.******** systemd[1]: httpd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 02 15:20:13 rp01.******** systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
-- 
-- Unit httpd.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
```

The symlink *is* readable to the apache user, `sudo -u apache cat /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts/data.conf` works nicely.

SELinux? But the context of the symlink is the same as the file it points to.

Any ideas?